# Custom Enviroment with tcolorbox/minted inside of marginfigure

Tags: margins, tcolorbox, minted

Trying to set up the following,

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

% Code Formatting Stuff
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\setminted{style=colorful, tabsize=2}
\newtcblisting{code}{
    size=minimal, boxsep=4pt, listing only, breakable,
    minted language=python
}
\newenvironment{codemargin}%
{\marginfigure\code}%
{\endcode\endmarginfigure}

\begin{document}
Here\\Is\\Some\\Text
\begin{codemargin}
here
is
some
code
\end{codemargin}
\end{document}
```

This results in `! File ended while scanning use of \next.`

Both `\newenviroment{codemargin}{\marginfigure}{\endmarginfigure}` and `\newenviroment{codemargin}{\code}{\endcode}` work, and using

```
\begin{marginfigure}
\begin{code}
here
is
some
code
\end{code}
\end{marginfigure}
```

all work, but putting the two together in a `\newenviroment` doesn't. I'm new to TeX, and don't really understand enough of what's going on to properly diagnose this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right solution, but it seems to work:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

% Code Formatting Stuff
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted, breakable}

% print page layout frames, can be commented
\geometry{showframe}


\setminted{style=colorful, tabsize=2}
\newtcblisting{code}{
    % option "breakable" is commented because a breakable tcolorbox in
    % marginnote is not supported
    size=minimal, boxsep=4pt, listing only, %breakable,
    minted language=python,
    before=\marginfigure, after=\endmarginfigure,
    width=\marginparwidth
}

\begin{document}
Here\\Is\\Some\\Text
\begin{code}
here
is
some
code
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had initially attempted that... It was erroring for me, because I was unaware that using breakable was unsupported. This works, thanks!